# Windows freezes on boot even after a fresh install. Can't even install linux due to a microcode error. What's happening?

Tags: hardware-failure, operating-systems

This has been plaguing me for months and I'm desperately trying to get this fixed, and could really use some help.

I woke up one morning to an unresponsive windows startup screen. Both mouse and keyboard input were completely frozen. After a reboot, the mouse and keyboard would be responsive for a split-second before the system froze again.

After unsuccessful troubleshooting, I attempted a fresh install of windows. Windows appeared to install fine, boot fine, then suddenly froze what appeared randomly as I'm setting up the new installation. Any subsequent rebooting caused the same freezing at the startup screen as before. I unsuccessfully played around in safe-mode, and tried a clean install again. The tl;dr here is that I'm pretty sure this crashing issue starts once windows update installs the intel graphics driver. (no gpu, using integrated graphics)

here's what I've tried

- updated & reset my bios
- removed all unnecessary components (storage hdd, pci cards)
- moved ram sticks to different slots
- *bought a new ssd*
- tried installing ubuntu*
- performed memtest86 (no errors)
- intalled an older intel graphics driver

I tried installing ubuntu, but when I tried to boot the live usb it gave  me this error:

`[Firmware_Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata: please update microcode to version 0x22 (or later)
Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000000e
MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e`

I've tried multiple usb's and iso's.

I'm thinking it's the mb at this point, but I don't know how to be sure, but the symptoms really don't seem like it.

At this point I'm totally lost. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which version of windows did you reinstall? Did you reinstall it in UEFI mode or withg CSM? Or is it a decade old laptop with BIOS fiormware? What is the model of the laptop?  Mostly asking due to all the problems I have had when installing win7 in MBR/CSM/BIOS mode on an EFI system which did not handle int13 graciously.  Also, it is always the same error, or did you try installing Ubuntu only once? If only once, is the CPU fan working?

Comment: It's a desktop I built myself 2 years ago. I believe I only used UEFI to install windows, but I did use both UEFI and CSM for Ubuntu - both modes gave me the same TSC_DEADLINE error. I'm running an i7 4790K with a Gigabyte z97x Gaming 7 mb.